# Why is a sniper rifle wealth 4 in open legend rpg?

Tags: weapons, pricing, designer-reasons, open-legend

Open legend, an open source rpg uses a wealth level system for equipment. It states that a sniper rifle requires wealth level 4. However, at the end of the same chapter it discusses how to price a weapon you design. Using the rifle I calculate a required wealth level of -1 (Weapons require a minimum of one) I can use their rules and make a better cheaper version of the weapon. Could anyone find some statement from the creator of the game or a solid line of reasoning why this would make sense to do?

[The rules regarding equipment and wealth](http://www.openlegendrpg.com/core-rules/05-wealth-equipment) are available online.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [designer-reasons questions are no longer allowed on RPG.SE](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/are-questions-about-rule-intent-on-topic).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's an error on their side which is going to be fixed. [I asked them on twitter](https://twitter.com/OpenLegendRPG/status/856078388779515904): they said they'll "be pushing a fix to the rules to correct the Sniper Rifle's WL" and linked to [the bug for the incorrect Sniper Rifle WL](https://github.com/openlegend/core-rules/issues/391).